# Xamarin Android Firebase implementation: IsEmailVerified remains false after reload

Tags: firebase, f#, xamarin.android

I'm working with the Nuget package Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.

In my Firebase console, I have set my email address verification link to match a dynamic link in my app. When the dynamic link is open,

```
FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser
```

is set to the user who clicked on the link, but its `IsEmailVerified` value is false. Even when I invoke:

```
let user = FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser
do! user.ReloadAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
let refreshedUser = FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser
```

the user's `IsEmailVerified` flag remains false, and I can't find a way to set it to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I misunderstood the email address verification link. I need to use the default value given in the Firebase console, but I need to supply my dynamic link from the codebase. The following line will add a `continueUrl` query parameter, which will invoke my dynamic link *after* the user has been verified:

```
let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.NewBuilder().SetUrl("https://my.dynamic.link.com/userverified").Build()
do! user.SendEmailVerificationAsync(actionCodeSettings) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

This was entirely my mistake, but I'll leave the answer here in case anyone makes a similar mistake.

**ADDENDUM**: You still have to reload the current user before the changes come through. The following lines are sufficient:

```
let user = FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser
do! user.ReloadAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
```